# How to open camera in black and white mode in android device

Tags: android, camera, imagefilter

I need to activate my camera in a black and white mode.

This is the first time  when i do this, so I have no idea of the manner I should use.

Please someone can change my code to open my camera in black and white mode .

```
 newImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //camera stuff
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

//folder stuff
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AirplaneSimsImages");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();

            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "AirplaneSims_" + timeStamp + ".png");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 100);
        }
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: you can't ... solutions: 1. convert the image to monochrome after intent returns 2. use camera directly with own preview window

Comment: @Selvin  how please?